Why is the operator in returning True?
This script returns True somehow, and it gets weirder if I ask to find in which index this is true.
I would expect it to check if [-1,0] is an element in the list mypolygon
import numpy as np
mypolygon = np.array([[0,0],[-3,1],[-1,1],[-2,4],[1,1],[3,3],[3,-2],[0,-2],[0,0]])
point = [-1, 0]
print(point in mypolygon)
print(np.where(mypolygon == point))


It prints:
True
(array([0, 2, 8]), array([1, 0, 1]))

How is the index 3-dimensional? What is going on?

This question is similar to: How does __contains__ work for ndarrays?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Where you hoping to get the same result as point in mypolygon.tolist()?  Don't assume that array in behaves the same as the list version.

point in mypolygon checks if the column-wise intersection of the list and the array is not null. For instance: [999, 0] in mypolygon returns True but [4, -3] in mypolygon returns False. It is equivalent to (mypolygon == point).any().
What you're looking for is most likely a broadcasted comparison along the first axis, then all + any:
(mypolygon == point).all(axis=1).any(axis=0)

Output: False.
Intermediate:
(mypolygon == point).all(axis=1)

# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])

In comparison, if you test with an existing point:
(mypolygon == [0, 0]).all(axis=1)

# array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True])

np.where returns the indices in which at least one coordinate is matching:
(mypolygon == point)

array([[False,  True],     # (0, 1)
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],     # (2, 0)
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True]])    # (8, 1)

np.where(mypolygon == point)

# first coordinate  second coordinate
(array([0, 2, 8]),  array([1, 0, 1]))

A pure python equivalent would be:
list(zip(*((i, j) for i, row in enumerate(mypolygon)
            for j, col in enumerate(row) if col == point[j])))
# [(0, 2, 8), (1, 0, 1)]


Do you know if the in behavior is properly documented somewhere? This is rather useless.

@nocomment unfortunately no. I've searched the documentation and couldn't find anything relevant. Even the source is not really explicit.

When you call mypolygon == point, numpy performs element wise comparison maintaining dimensions of the coordinates:

it checks for -1 in the first column (x-coordinates)
it checks for 0 in the second column (y-coordinates)

np.where() returns array with indices by dimension, where the values in point occur in mypolygon (at same columns). It is "3-dimensionnal" because it found 3 occurences:

-1 at one index in mypolygon (1st column): at [2, 0]
0 at two indexes in mypolygon (2nd column): at [0, 1], [8, 1]

for what you are trying to achieve, you could use:
print(np.all(mypolygon == point, axis=1))


np.all(..., axis=1) checks if all coordinates matches along each row
True indexes will get you the n-th row values that matches point

